# I have a list of questions, when I try to get data from it, it gives me a null output

Tags: flutter, dart, chrome-app-developer-tool

This is the error I got : The body might complete normally, causing
"null" to be returned, but the return type, 'List quiz', is a potentially non-nullable type

Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

```
List<soal> getsoals() {
  var solayek = soal();
  solayek.soalcode = 1;
  solayek.soaltitle = 'تعداد حلقه های المپیک؟';
  solayek.pasokhlist = ['5عدد', '6عدد', '7عدد', '8عدد'];
  solayek.pasokhdorst = 0;
  solayek.point = 10;
  var solado = soal();
  solado.soalcode = 2;
  solado.soaltitle = 'تعداد اعضای شورای نگهبان؟';
  solado.pasokhlist = ['شش نفر', 'هشت نفر', 'سیزده نفر', 'دوازده نفر'];
  solado.pasokhdorst = 3;
  solado.point = 10;
  var solase = soal();
  solase.soalcode = 3;
  solase.soaltitle = 'ارتفاعات سهند در کدام استان قرار دارد؟';
  solase.pasokhlist = ['آذربایجان شرقی', 'آذربایجان غربی', 'کردستان', 'زنجان'];
  solase.pasokhdorst = 0;
```

Comment: What's the last line of your function look like.  Are you returning a List or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this error, you need to add a return statement at the end of the function that returns a List of soal objects. For example:

```
List<soal> getsoals() {
  var solayek = soal();
  solayek.soalcode = 1;
  solayek.soaltitle = 'تعداد حلقه های المپیک؟';
  solayek.pasokhlist = ['5عدد', '6عدد', '7عدد', '8عدد'];
  solayek.pasokhdorst = 0;
  solayek.point = 10;
  var solado = soal();
  solado.soalcode = 2;
  solado.soaltitle = 'تعداد اعضای شورای نگهبان؟';
  solado.pasokhlist = ['شش نفر', 'هشت نفر', 'سیزده نفر', 'دوازده نفر'];
  solado.pasokhdorst = 3;
  solado.point = 10;
  var solase = soal();
  solase.soalcode = 3;
  solase.soaltitle = 'ارتفاعات سهند در کدام استان قرار دارد؟';
  solase.pasokhlist = ['آذربایجان شرقی', 'آذربایجان غربی', 'کردستان', 'زنجان'];
  solase.pasokhdorst = 0;

  // Create a List containing the objects you've created
  List<soal> soalsList = [solayek, solado, solase];

  // Return the List
  return soalsList;
}
```